# Covariant transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have difficulty understanding contravariant and covariant. So I wrote this, using Einstein summation convention, but only $k$ means summation

A point $\mathrm{P}\in \mathcal{R}^n$ has coordinates $\textbf{p}_R=[p^1,\cdots,p^n]^{\mathrm{T}}$. Introduce ($V$) basis vectors $X=(\textbf{x}_1,\cdots,\textbf{x}_n) : \textbf{x}_j   =[x_j^1,\cdots,x_j^n]^{\mathrm{T}}$ which generate coordinate vectors $\textbf{p}_{X}=[ v^1,\cdots,v^n]^{\mathrm{T}}  : \textbf{p}_R= v^k\textbf{x}_k\equiv \textbf{A}_{X} \textbf{p}_X$, with $x^i_j$ being the $(i,j)$ element of matrix  $\textbf{A}_{X}$ and $p^i =v^kx^i_k $.

Alternative basis vectors $E=(\textbf{e}_1,\cdots,\textbf{e}_n) : \textbf{e}_j   =[e_j^1,\cdots,e_j^n]^{\mathrm{T}} $ generating $\textbf{p}_{E}=[ r^1,\cdots,r^n]^{\mathrm{T}} : \textbf{p}_R= r^k\textbf{e}_k\equiv \textbf{A}_{E} \textbf{p}_E$, with $e^i_j$ being the $(i,j)$ element of matrix $\textbf{A}_{E}$ and $p^i =r^ke^i_k $.

Writing $\textbf{e}_j   = b_j^k \textbf{x}_k$, then $e_j^i   = b_j^k x_k^i$ and the transformation $X\mapsto E$ is given by $\textbf{A}_E=\textbf{A}_X\textbf{B}_{X\mapsto E}$, with $b^i_j$ as the $(i,j)$ element of matrix $\textbf{B}_{X\mapsto E}$.

Then, $\textbf{A}_{X} \textbf{p}_X=\textbf{A}_{E} \textbf{p}_E=\textbf{A}_X\textbf{B}_{X\mapsto E}\textbf{p}_E$ and the transformation $\textbf{p}_X\mapsto  \textbf{p}_E$ is given by $\textbf{p}_E = \textbf{B}^{-1}_{X\mapsto E}\textbf{p}_X$ and hence a contravariant transformation.

It looks like any basis is a contravariant transformation. So then I wrote this:

$V^*$ is the set of linear functionals $\varphi:V\mapsto \mathcal{R}$; add $(\phi + \varphi)(\textbf{p})=\phi(\textbf{p})+\varphi(\textbf{p})$; $(a\varphi)(\textbf{p})=a(\varphi(\textbf{p}))$ for $a\in \mathcal{R}$; $\textbf{p}\in V$; $\varphi, \phi \in V^*$, then $V^*$ is also a vector space. A particular basis of $V^*$ is the dual of $X$ and is the set of linear functionals $X^*=(\textbf{f}^1,\cdots,\textbf{f}^n) : \textbf{f}^i(\textbf{x}_j) =\delta^i_j  $, generating $\textbf{p}_{X^*}=[s_1,\cdots,s_n] : \textbf{p}_R=s_k\textbf{f}^k $. Since $s_i\textbf{f}^i(\textbf{x}_j)=s_i\delta_j^i=s_i$ then $\textbf{p}_R(X)=\textbf{p}_{X^*}$. Somehow I think this leads to a covariant transformation.

But my main question is what is it about the first approach that always results in a contravariant transformation. Is it something about  $\textbf{A}_{X} \textbf{p}_X=\textbf{A}_{E} \textbf{p}_E=\textbf{A}_X\textbf{B}_{X\mapsto E}\textbf{p}_E$?

Comment: So you are asking why the dual map is a contravariant tensor?

Comment: I think the dual leads to covariant, but I can't get there. The main question is

Comment: about the first approach.

Comment: But do you agree vector transformation is covariant?

Comment: Transformation could be either. I am trying to figure out what it means.

Comment: Well the convention is that we agree vectors transform covariantly and its dual transforms contravariantly. You have to agree on one of them first to get to the other.